# Chrome reduced the width of the <a> tag on hover

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I built a simple dropdown menu, but in Chrome on hover the size of the  tag reduced by 3px. (jump effect)

I don't understand where's the problem, here is my css:

```
#primary {
    width:400px;
    background:yellow;
    height:48px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#primary li {
    display:table;
    width:120px;
    float:left;
    border-right:1px solid blue;
    position:relative;
}

#primary li a { 
    display:table-cell;
    text-align:center;
    height:48px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}

#primary #secondary {
    display:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#primary li:hover #secondary {
    position:absolute;
    top:48px;
    left:0;
    background:red;
    display:block;
}
```

It seems Chrome adds extra hidden margin/padding.. In FF, IE it's working.

Online demo: http://jsfiddle.net/A3XDR/

Comment: Why not add `display: block;` to your a instead of `display: table-cell`?

Comment: I would like to center the navigation items vertically.

Comment: But you are forcing the browser now to come up with creative solutions to the structure you provide. For one thing, there's nothing with `display:table-row` in your document. And you have a `table-cell` right next to a `block`. That is confusing. When written out as HTML elements instead of CSS properties, it wouldn't validate.

Comment: Yes, in HTML it's confusing.. but do you really think it's problem in CSS? Many developers use `table-cell` propery inside `table`, without `table-row`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way to do it but it involves changing your markup, adding a `span` within the link:

HTML:

```
<ul id="primary">
    <li>
        <a href=""><span>Nav 1 is long and wraps some</span></a>
        <ul id="secondary">
            <li><a href="">Nav 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Nav 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Nav 1-3</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Nav 1-4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href=""><span>Nav 2</span></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><span>Nav 3</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#primary li a { 
    display:table;
    height:48px;
    width: 100%;
}

#primary li a > span {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A3XDR/7/) | [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/qejogufu/1) (for IE8 testing, jsFiddle doesn't work on IE8)

(You can also change `#primary li` to `display: block` if that table-in-table bothers you; seems to work: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A3XDR/8/) | [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/qejogufu/2))

No jumping for me in the older Chrome (~v26) that has issues with just the simple `width: 100%`, or with the long nav entry that wraps which jumps for me even on current Chrome (~v32). Also seems happy in Firefox, IE8, IE10, Opera, and Midori.

*(This solution is **only** possible because of the direction [putvande](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21852747/157247) and [Lokesh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21852834/157247) pointed in. Please show your support for their efforts.)*

Comment: No jumping at all in this. But I still don't understand why it didn't work on 100% width?

Comment: @LokeshSuthar: I don't understand it either. :-) But [your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A3XDR/2/) jumps (*less*, but definitely there) in older Chrome (~v26), and [this one with a wider label](http://jsfiddle.net/A3XDR/4/) jumps even in the current Chrome (~v32), watch the word "wrap" at the end. With the extra span and markup, we make it completely solid.

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
#primary li a { 
    display:table-cell;
    text-align:center;
    height:48px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

to

```
#primary li a { 
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    height:48px;
    line-height: 48px;
}
```

If you want to keep your vertical alignment and `table-cell` you could add `width: 100%`:

```
#primary li a { 
    display:table-cell;
    text-align:center;
    height:48px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width: 100%; 
}
```

Comment: I have long items in the navigation, so the line-height not a perfect choice. That's why I choosed table-cell.

Comment: Ah, the good old CSS failure on vertical centering... If only, when they were doing CSS, there'd been something like 25 years of prior art they could have drawn on. Oh, wait, there was.

Comment: With your second solution, `width: 100%`, it still jumps for me in Chrome. Not as much, but enough that it's still a problem. - http://jsfiddle.net/A3XDR/3/

Comment: I thought there was a consensus to do vertical align by means of `line-height`.

Comment: @MrLister: Unless of course there's more than one line of text, as in the OP's case. In any case, that's a workaround, not a properly-designed model.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder. It is not jumping for me in Chrome. What version do you have?

Comment: @putvande: I'm a bit out of date, v26.0.1410.63 on Linux. Using v32.0.1700.107 on Windows I don't see it unless the label is long and wraps, then the trailing bit at the bottom moves even on the latest Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/A3XDR/4/

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick but I am not sure why is it behaving like this. It is surely because of secondary ul but not sure why.

```
#primary li a { 
    display:table-cell;
    text-align:center;
    height:48px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    width:100%;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A3XDR/2/)**

Comment: Still moves in Chrome for me.

Comment: for me too, but it's smaller jump :)

Comment: What version of chrome are you guys using? because it doesn't move at all for me

Comment: Not even a single pixel.

Comment: Can't detect any movement in Chrome 32.017 on this solution even with large zoom.

Comment: Version 32.0.1700.107

Comment: I see the change, the 'jump' is smaller, but not 100% perfect.

Comment: See the comments on putvande's answer. Jumps with longer text (which is apparently the OP's reason for not using line-height): http://jsfiddle.net/A3XDR/4/ even on current Chrome; jumps with shorter text on older Chrome (v26mumble).